# 404 error The requested resource is not available in apache tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I am not using `Eclipse` nor `Netbean`. I have source code of this project, I copied and paste project in `webapps`, then after opening the server /online quiz after clicking on not getting home page it gives error of

> 404 error The requested resource is not available.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: 404 means page not found what url u used to run the application also did you checked if project deployed or not?

Comment: Also you deployed `war` file or `folder` of the project ?

Answer (score 1):

```
i copied n paste project in webapps
```

You should put only .class files (not .java files).
Also, since it is a webapp, tomcat requires a specific folder structure.
Follow this link,
[Webapp file organization convention (development structure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198942/webapp-file-organization-convention-development-structure)