# Where web.xml should be in a Java EE project using Intellij IDEA IDE?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, web.xml

In a Java EE project, where the `web.xml` file should be?

- `project/WebContent/WEB-INF`
- `project/webapp/WEB-INF`
- `project/src/main/WebContent/WEB-INF`
- `project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`

There is a way of changing that?

Comment: Where do you have it right now? Did you try searching with Google with a search string like this: _intellij idea java web application web.xml_ - there are quite a few results discussing the subject in question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webapp file organization convention (development structure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198942/webapp-file-organization-convention-development-structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends the Dynamic Web Module facet you choosed and the configuration for the web resources in the project properties.